# How can ng-route of angularjs and @app.route of flask be used together?

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I am trying to integrate flask and angular ng-route.
I am developing a webapp with python algorithms in backand for which flask is very helpful and I have chosen angular for client side scripting.

```
import os
from flask import render_template,Flask, jsonify, request,redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from flask_restful import Resource,Api

app= Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/index2')
def index2():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The above is the flask code and the angular code follows:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", ["ngRoute"])
    myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
                    $routeProvider.when('/',{
                        templateUrl: 'index'
                    })
                    .when('/home',{
                        templateUrl: 'dashboard'
                    })
                    .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    });
                });
    myApp.controller("loginCtrl", function($scope, $location){
        $scope.submit = function(){
            var uname=$sope.username;
            var password = $scope.password;
            if ($scope.username=="admin" && $scope.password=="admin")
                $location.path('/dashboard');
                $location.path('/dashboard');
        }
    });
```

Problem : Even though it doesn't show any error it doesn't redirect to the correct paths as expected.

Comment: What is the exact problem you encountered? What are your expectations, what is not working?

Comment: it shows no error but doesnot redirect to the respective partials